# How to replace a html tag in js?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, replace

I have a string in which there are continous occurances of a font tag

```
 <font color="blue">DATA ENTRY</font>
```

and in some cases like this

```
 <font class="beat">DATA ENTRY</font>
```

I want to replace the 2 tags with

So that it looks like this

```
     <p>DATA ENTRY</p>
```

I tried this ,can anyone please suggest me help.Thanks.

```
 text = text.replace('<font [^"]*>',<p>).replace('</font>','');
```

Comment: The `<font>` is a deprecated tag. Is there a reason why you *need* to use it? You could instead use the same `<p>` tag and just remove the class later.

Comment: Hi Nikhil,I am geeting this data from client side which I cannot manipulate.

Comment: Don't use regex with HTML. Instead convert it to a temporary DOM Element, manipulate it, and then convert back to text if needed.

Comment: @Nicer getting this data from client side means? you have to convert in server side (javascript in nodejs) or client side (javascript in browser)?

Comment: @Nicer angular & javascript you are using are the client side. Do you mean you can't touch the HTML ?

Comment: @Nicer exactly...

Comment: I mean I am getting data from a remote area which I cant touch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to stick with your simple string manipulation, you need to use regular expressions and correct the replacements in your `replace` calls:

```
text = text.replace(/<font[^>]*>/g,'<p>').replace(/<\/font>/g,'</p>');
```

Answer (score 9):

```
block.outerHTML = "<p>" + block.innerHTML + "</p>"
```

where block is any HTML block
it just left to select it correctly with:

var block = document.querySelector(".selector");

Comment: Didn't think about `outerHTML` being writeable. Good to know it is. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3):

Since you just need to replace the string you can do this with just one replace statement.

```
text = text.replace(/<(\/*)font[^>]*>/g, '<$1p>');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you using jQuery with [replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)

```
$('font').replaceWith('<p>DATA ENTRY</p>');
```

Comment: OP is using Angular js.So,I think using jquery might not be an good option.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the `font` tag is deprecated and should not be used.

1. **Get an array of the tags you want to replace.**

   ```
   var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('font');
   ```
2. **Go through loop and replace old HTML with new HTML**

   ```
   for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
   {
       var target = elems[i].innerHTML;
       elems[i].innerHTML = target.replace(/(<p)/igm, '<font').replace(/<\/p>/igm, '</font>');
   }
   ```

Note: This is not tested but should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
$('font').contents().unwrap().wrap('<p/>');
```

In javascript, you can do something like this :

```
var str="<font>hello world</font>";   
str = str.replace(/<font>/, "<p>");  
str = str.replace(/<\/font>/,"</p>");
```

Comment: OP is using Angular js.So,I think using jquery might not be an good option.