# how we can replace particular span tag to particular label tag in JavaScript only

Tags: javascript

Input:

```html
<span class="bold">Themes </span>and styles also help to keep your document <span class="italic">coordinated</span>. When you click Design and choose a new Theme, the pictures, <span class="underline">charts </span>and SmartArt graphics change to match your new theme. When you apply styles, your headings change to match the new theme
```

Output needed:

```html
<b>Themes </b>and styles also help to keep your document <i>coordinated</i>. When you click Design and choose a new Theme, the pictures, <u>charts </u>and SmartArt graphics change to match your new theme. When you apply styles, your headings change to match the new theme
```

I tried like this:

```
const getEditorField = document.getElementById('editorField').innerHTML;
if (getEditorField.match(/\bbold\b/)) {
    getEditorField = getEditorField.replace(/<\/?span[^>]*>/gi, '<b>');
    } else if (getEditorField.match(/\bitalic\b/)) {
        getEditorField = getEditorField.replace(/(?<=<(?:\/)?)span(?:.*?)(?<!>)/gi, 'i');
    } else if (getEditorField.match(/\bunderline\b/)) {
        getEditorField = getEditorField.replace(/(?<=<(?:\/)?)span(?:.*?)(?<!>)/gi, 'u');
    }
```

But I am not sure why I am not actually getting the output that I want.

Comment: This may help , [Replace Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45055562/how-to-replace-a-html-tag-in-js)

Comment: Why not just apply the appropriate css?

Comment: no @Nick i want to apply in custom HTML format so i need to replace particular tag to different tag name and i don't want to apply CSS and question is [i need in JavaScript only]

Comment: @Sakil The dup you've proposed contains awful answers, the only good answer is Gyan's, but it uses jQuery.

Comment: If you are changing them purely for styling purposes, then it's better to leave them as they are as these tags have different meaning in html 5 than they used to  - they are now not for bold, italic and underline (using them for styling was deprecated since html 4); they are now meant for `b` - bring attention to, `i` - idiomatic text and `u` - unarticulated annotation

Comment: @Pete I truly agree with you but I really need to convert/replace tag to another tag how i shown in output example

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using a regex, you could just use a query selector to select the elements and then use `replaceWith` to replace them with the element you want:

```js
function replaceElement(selector, tag) {
  document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach(element => {
    const replacement = document.createElement(tag);
    replacement.innerHTML = element.innerHTML;
    element.replaceWith(replacement);
  });
}

replaceElement('span.bold', 'b');
replaceElement('span.italic', 'i');
replaceElement('span.underline', 'u');
```

```html
<span class="bold">Themes </span>and styles also help to keep your document 
<span class="italic">coordinated</span>. When you click Design and choose a new Theme, the pictures, 
<span class="underline">charts </span>and SmartArt graphics change to match
your new theme. When you apply styles, your headings change to match the new theme
```

If you only have a string, I would just put it in an element and still use query selector on it:

```js
const html = `<span class="bold">Themes </span>and styles also help to keep your document 
<span class="italic">coordinated</span>. When you click Design and choose a new Theme, the pictures, 
<span class="underline">charts </span>and SmartArt graphics change to match
your new theme. When you apply styles, your headings change to match the new theme`;

const temp = document.createElement('div');
temp.innerHTML = html;

function replaceElement(selector, tag) {
  temp.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach(element => {
    const replacement = document.createElement(tag);
    replacement.innerHTML = element.innerHTML;
    element.replaceWith(replacement);
  });
}

replaceElement('span.bold', 'b');
replaceElement('span.italic', 'i');
replaceElement('span.underline', 'u');

document.body.innerHTML = temp.innerHTML;
```

Comment: I can say this will be best answer for query selector purpose.
`let getEditorField = document.getElementById('editorField').innerHTML;` in this am having whole string that contains bold,italic,underline,.etc., and i want return result/output in getEditorField variable

Comment: you could just do the query selector on your editor field: `document.getElementById('editorField').querySelectorAll`  if you only have the string by the time you get to the change point, you could create an element and put the string in there and use the query selector on the created element

Comment: yeah got it. got answer 
thank you very much @pete